# Can I say 'at afternoon' anyhow?

Tags: prepositions

I found in a book where I saw 'at' before afternoon.
Can I use it anyhow?
I know that 'in the afternoon' is often used.

Comment: If you say "at an afternoon performance/wedding/ etc.", then yeah it is correct.

Comment: In the afternoon/ at afternoon

Comment: "_at afternoon_" is never correct in English as a subsitution for _"in the afternoon_". You would only see this construction when _afternoon_ is used attributively, as in "_at afternoon tea._"

Comment: He who used it has a bechelor and master's degree in English from a renowned university in our country Bangladesh, a neighbouring country of India. He recieved many international awards for his innovation of teaching and learning English method named 'FM Method'. Never have I found 'at' used this without his book. He used it in a few lessons. That is why I am cofused and cofused.

Comment: Whatever degree he may have from a university in Bangladesh, he does not speak English very well at all. The expression _"at afternoon"_ (except attributively as above) is just plain bad English. This fellow Mukul who sells the 'FM Method' is a fraud, liar, and a charlatan. His courses are a joke and he is a thief. His writing is hilariously ungrammatical. Unfortunately, it is easy to be an "expert" when there are no English speakers present. We have a saying in English: _"In the land of the blind, the one-eyed man is king."_

Comment: Grateful to you. I am much more satisfied with your answer.

Comment: Please advise any Bangladeshi students not to give any of their money or time to this fraud. There are many real instructors available. This fellow ought to be prosecuted.

Comment: @P.E.Dant You really need to be very careful before slinging around accusations of fraudulency. You might be liable for a writ. The PP *at afternoon* used to be reasonably frequent a hundred and fifty years ago in British English. Indian English, which is its own variety,  quite often uses English that is so antiquated that modern users wouldn't recognise it, but is nonetheless standard over there. So if people in Sri Lanka are being taught English to communicate with Indian English speakers, that may well be a PP that you might hear.

Comment: @P.E.Dant [See the first four pages here for examples from the 1800s](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22a+nearly+100+percent+pass+rate%22&oq=%22a+nearly+100+percent+pass+rate%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.9417j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22at+afternoon%22&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1800,cd_max:1899&tbm=bks&start=30), for instance

Comment: @P.E.Dant Note that those examples include instances from both Francis Bacon and Robert Browning amongst others.

Comment: He, Feruz Mukul was a five-time-debate champion at inter-university debate competetion in English arranged by Chakahoo.

Comment: @Araucaria Let him writ away, then. I encourage you to peruse this fellow's website, to investigate some of the "awards" he claims, and to read some of his writing. The aroma of chicanery is unmistakable.

Comment: @AbuNaimMuhammedKalil Please do not be deceived. Mr Mukul is a businessman only, and his objective is to sell products, nothing else. He is a salesman of franchises. No-one outside of your country has heard of any of the "awards" he claims. One of them is itself a scam!

Comment: @Araucaria To compare this mountebank to Bacon and Browning is an insult to them both. Please visit his website, where he informs us that he won the "Helen Keler Gold Medal 2009" and that _"converting Bengali into English is like carrying a passenger from one place to another, (from Bengali to English) where a vehicle is needed, but to say about grammar (the law enforcing agency of the English Language), is totally unbecoming and unwelcoming."_ Many other howlers are available among the sales pitches for franchises and books.

Comment: To be frank, in a small town where I live there is a franchised branch where I teach students following his method. That's to say I am a teacher of this branch teaching what I know.

Comment: I'm a one-eyed king in the land of blind.

Comment: @P.E.Dant OK, that all looks pretty uncinvincing, I grant you.

Answer (score 1):

In contemporary English, in countries where English is the first language, the preposition **at**, when used with time-phrases, wants as its complement a *point or moment in time*, not a *time-span*; since **afternoon** refers to a time-span between noon and the early part of the evening, it is not a valid complement for **at**.  To state it the other way around, **at** is not a valid preposition for a time-span.

at 6AM

at noon

at nightfall

at dawn

at dinnertime

at lunchtime

at the outset

at the beginning

at the end

at inception

at commencement

Comment: My English can be attributed to his method. I stydied English Grammar in Use by Reymond Murphy, Advanced Grammar in Use by Martin Hewings and also 'A Passage to English by S.M. Zakir Hossain. I built a foundation over English using his method. But only 'at' is what that I disagree with him about.

Comment: @AbuNaimMuhammedKalil  "You will be convinced to believe that, FM Method starts from where English Grammar ends," says Mukul's website (where he offers franchise opportunities to unwitting dupes.) I could cite dozens of other, similar examples of bad writing. You are well advised to continue with Murphy, and to seek real instruction from an English speaker.

Comment: I beg your pardon that I'm having you talking. I need more help of yours.

Comment: We are happy to assist you here, and in your country, I am sure that there are reputable and honest teachers who will instruct you. The USIA, through the U.S. Embassy in Dhaka, offers a number of programs. Please visit [**this link**](https://bd.usembassy.gov/education-culture/english-language-programs/) to learn more.

Comment: The problem with English to English grammar is it never explains what means what in other language. How can we learn a foreign language from a foreign book where we don't know basic of it. In this case, we need a book that helps us what a sentence or phrase means in our own language.

Comment: @AbuNaimMuhammedKalil To really learn any new language, a student must _abandon_ the security of the native language, not cling to it. To speak English, Bengali, or Kazakh, one must _think_ in that new language. To do otherwise is to be merely a translator. That is why Mukul's product, and others like it, are snake oil. A student of his dropped on the street in New York, London, or Cape Town, will be lost. There is no "magic formula" whereby Bengali or any other language can be converted into English. There is more...(cont. below)

Comment: @AbuNaimMuhammedKalil The "London Quality Crown Award 2010" which Mukul claims to have "won" does not exist in London or anywhere else; so for the "International Star Award". These "awards" and the others are all scams: they require the "winner" to pay exorbitant "entrance fees". For example, see [**here**](http://www.observer.org.sz/news/74845-salesian-high-targeted-for-awards-scam.html) and [**here.**](http://www.sundaytimes.lk/120916/news/debt-ridden-loss-making-sec-pays-for-dubious-award-12695.html) The victims are always naive persons and companies in non-English speaking countries.

Comment: I see. Where are you from, please?

Comment: @AbuNaimMuhammedKalil Presently I live in the United States. I have also lived in Switzerland. France, and Italy. For your sake, I hope you believe me when I tell you that those "awards" are utterly phony.

Comment: I'm grateful to you for your kind responses.